# Processing toolbox nowhere to be found

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I have just downloaded the newest version of QGIS (3.2) and the processing toolbox is nowhere to be found. It says that it is now apart of the core package, but i cannot find it on anywhere on the program.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. 3.16, Windows 7 (b/c reasons). Vector drop down menu is empty; there is no Processing toolbox or Processing menu.

I have seen many comments saying go to Plugins and enable the Processing Plugin, which is supposed to be a core plugin already installed, but the plugin is not even there so I can't enable it.

Ctrl+Alt+T does nothing. I looked for the plugin to download and install it, but I could not find it on the QGIS website. Ideas anyone?

Comment: Update: I uninstalled and then installed QGIS 3.10.14 instead, and the Processing plugin and tools are showing up now.

Answer (score 16):

You have to activate the plugin "Processing" in the Plugin-Manager.

Comment: I had done 1001 things but this was the problem all the time. thanks.

Comment: Why it's not on by default is beyond me...

Answer (score 8):

You can open it up with Ctrl + Alt + T.

Or you can click on the Processing Toolbox Icon:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on Processing > Toolbox on the Menu Toolbar. Then you can bring it back with Ctl+Alt+T.

Answer (score 1):

@Arthur R, thank you. That is correct and totally fixed it: enable "Processing" plug-in.
Other answers that reference Processing drop down menu, the toolbox symbol, or ctrl+alt+t are not helpful for this issue because none of those appear without the plug-in enabled.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/241613)

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling 'Processing' in plugins by unchecking it. Close the plugins pop-up.

Re-open plugins and re-enable 'Processing'. Close the plugins pop-up again.

Look for the icon in the toolbar or press `CTRL+ALT+T`