# QGIS: Intersect rasterdata with vectorline

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, intersect

I am new to QGIS. 
My aim is to be able to get information of the height at any point on my vector line. My raster is a map with height information in the format geotiff. The vector layer is in the shape format.

I tried to intersect them but it wouldn't work, I guess because they are not the same format. I also tried to vectorize the raster layer and use the plugin refFunction and geomwithin but it wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the QGIS plugin [Profile tool](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/profiletool/)?

With this plugin you can get the exact elevation just by moving the cursor over the graph. You can also export a table with elevation data for your line.

[image: Line on top of a DEM]
[image: Profile tool]

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to avoid moving the cursor over the map and instead using a vectorlayer to tell the program where I want to know the elevation?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. Where along this line do you need your elevation info? Every vertex node? Or every xx kilometers?

Comment: Basically every few metres along the line.

Comment: Then I'd recommend the answer by @csk, convert line to points!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to *do* with the elevation information.

**If you want the elevation stored in the attribute table**, you have to convert the line to points. QGIS can't store data "at any point on a vector line" because the line only has one entry in the attribute table.

First convert your line to points, using the `extract vertices` or `points along geometry` algorithm.

Use the GRASS algorithm `v.sample` or the QGIS algorithm `Sample raster values` to apply the raster data to the points as an attribute.

Note: all algorithms mentioned in the answer can be found in the [Processing Toolbox](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291328/processing-toolbox-nowhere-to-be-found).

**If you want to find the elevation at a single point along the line**, you can use the Identify tool in "Top Down" mode.

**If you want to get the elevation in the expression builder**, you can use the `raster_value()` function, for example:

```
raster_value('mypointlayer',1,$geometry)
```

Again it requires a point rather than a line as input. There are various ways to write a point into the equation, for example using the `line_interpolate_point()`.

Comment: To be honest I already fail to convert the line to points. The only time this worked I got points somewhere near the line or even just at certain vertex. Could you explain me in a few steps how to convert the vector line into points every few meter?

Comment: The extract vertices tool does exactly what its name says: it extracts the **vertices** of the line. If your line doesn't have enough vertices, you can add them using the `Densify by interval` tool.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another method, in QGIS 3.4 you can save the height of the raster in the Z variable of each vertex of the geometries (points, lines or polygons) of a vector layer, with the *[Drape (set Z value from raster)](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#drape-set-z-value-from-raster-34)* tool.